# How to read the buffer from a paquet (tftp)

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, packet, tftp

I am currently trying to write a tftp in C. But i have some difficulties to read the packet that I sent.
Here is what I have :
The struct that I am sending :

```
typedef struct {
short type;
short block_num;
char* data;
} data_t;
```

the function (server's side) wich send the packet :

```
 if ( s = sendto (serverSocket, data, 512 ,0,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0 )
                {
                    perror("sendto");
                    exit(1);
                }
```

For some reason s = 0, I am not sure it is correct.

Client's side :

```
  char buffer[512 ];
  if ( (n = recv(serverSocket, buffer, 512-1,0)) < 0 )
        {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
   data_t * data = malloc (1024);
   data->data = malloc(512);
   create_data(buffer,data)
```

and the create_data function :

```
int create_data( char * buffer, data_t* request)

{

data_t * tmp = (data_t*) buffer;
request->type = tmp->type;
request->block_num = tmp->block_num;
strcpy(request->data, tmp->data);
return 0;
}
```

Unfortunatly it does not work, it seems the issue comes from strcpy in create_data , but I don't know why.

here is the code for serverSocket creation (server's side)

```
memset( (char *) &serv_addr,0, sizeof(serv_addr) );
serv_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);

/*
* Ouvrir socket UDP
*/
if ((serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) <0)
{
    perror ("erreur socket");
    exit (1);
}
ttl=1;
if (setsockopt(serverSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl)) <0)
{
    perror ("setsockopt");
    exit (1);
}
if ( bind(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *) & serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) ) < 0 )
{
    perror("servecho: erreur bind\n");
    exit(1);
}

request = malloc(sizeof(request_t));
                    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sendto returns number of bytes sent, so if it is returning 0, no bytes have been sent.

In the server part of code, you seem to have a sendto with destination as server address ? (which has INETADDR_ANY as the address). This could be the reason for malfunction.  The procedure should be to have the server do a recvfrom first (after bind) and then respond back with sendto, to same address received in recvfrom. 
Here is a good example for [Server](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6xconlessserver.htm) and [Client](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/rzab6/rzab6xconlessclient.htm).

Received data or data to be sent is binary, you cannot use strcpy, strcpy will stop at the first null byte '\0', you need to use memcpy.

Good practice: While allocating memory  `data_t * data = malloc (1024);`, I recommend you use malloc( sizeof(data_t));

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with the sendto even if instead of data I send a string it will still return 0.

Comment: Not that part, the one where you create serverSocket with socket() and  presume you would be using initialization of sockaddr_in